# Proper parsing of "Ite, missa est"

Tags: idiom, latin-to-english-translation, christianity

In the Catholic liturgy at the dismissal, the Latin phrase used is "Ite, missa est." The usual translation for this is "Go, the Mass has ended."

Can someone suggest a proper parsing of this somewhat opaque phrase?

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article about this phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ite,_missa_est)?

Comment: I read another (somewhat similar) article at the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08253a.htm)--I was struck by the wide range of interpretations and (apparent) lack of consensus for something that seems rather simple

Comment: The elliptic interpretation as *Ite, missa est congregatio* (or with some other feminine noun) is most appealing to me, but I have nothing but classically oriented taste to back this up with.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Assuming your interpretation is correct (which I don't know), I think that in Classical Latin it would be better to say: _Ite, **di**missa est **con**gregatio_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase is confusing if one assumes that *missa* is a perfect passive participle, since it has no obvious antecedent. The ending dialogue of the (Pauline/Novus Ordo) mass goes,

> V: Benedicat vos Omnipotens Deus: Pater, Filius et Spiritus Sanctus.
>
> R: Amen.
>
> V: Ite, missa est.
>
> R: Deo gratias.

One could guess that it is the *benedictio* that is sent. But in the older form of the mass, this blessing does not come until after the *Ite missa est* (the *Ita missa est* is preceded only by *Dominus vobiscum / Et cum spiritu tuo*). One might guess that the antecedent is something else like *ecclesia* or *congregatio*, but any proposed answer would be at best a guess. There is no sure historical answer. There was no liturgical committee from, say, the fourth century that composed this form out of nothing and wrote down exactly what they were thinking when they did.

The more probably and generally accepted answer is that *missa* in this case is probably not a perfect passive participle at all. It is just an alternative form of the noun *missio*, i.e. dismissal. The Catholic Encyclopedia provides some analogous cases.

> Before it became the technical name of the holy Liturgy in the Roman
>   Rite, it meant simply "dismissal". The form missa for missio is like
>   that of collecta (for collectio), ascensa (ascensio), etc. So Ite
>   missa est should be translated "Go it is the dismissal."
>
> http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08253a.htm

So *missa* is just a first declension, singular, nominative noun, meaning, "dismissal."

Comment: Interesting--if that is the case, do you know if there are any previous examples of "missa" being used as a substantive? I always assumed collecta = oratio collecta, or something similar.

Comment: I don't know of any examples of *missa* as dismissal (prior the phrase being used in the mass) off the top of my head. In English, "collected" and "collection" are not exact synonyms, but they have an overlap in meaning. "Collection" can be not just the act of collecting, but also what is collected. You can see how in Latin a word like *missa* could take on the action-meaning of *missio*.

Your interpretation of "collecta" as "oratio collecta" works grammatically, so a clearer parallel example might be the use of the phrase *Ascensa Domini* for *Ascensio Domini.*

Comment: That sparked a pretty interesting find which you might want to incorporate in your answer: [footnote e of pg. 1353 of S. Benedicti Abbatis Anianensis *Concordia Regularum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aJRBAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PT552&lpg=RA1-PT552&dq=ascensa+domini&source=bl&ots=-G7tqbNNV9&sig=aPyskaWMo0ScsaD9eW1IoLD4Wa4&hl=la&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwintPfDy5nMAhVBkYMKHVG1BckQ6AEIMTAG#v=onepage&q=ascensa%20domini&f=false) has some cool examples of this transformation from early authors like Tertullian and Cyprian.

Comment: Most of the examples in the footnote are of *remissa* meaning *remissio*

Answer (score 10):

This comes from Dom Prosper Guéranger's [*Explanation of the Prayers and Ceremonies of Holy Mass*](http://www.liturgialatina.org/benedictine/holymass.htm#itemissa):

> #### ITE MISSA EST.
>
> These words are usually translated thus: “Go, the Mass is said.”
>   However, we must here observe that this is not their proper sense.
>   This formula, adopted by the Church, was in general use amongst the
>   Romans, in public assemblies, to announce the termination of the
>   meeting. So, these words: *Ite, concio missa est,* meant “go, the
>   assembly is dismissed.”
>
> In the early ages, the Holy Sacrifice was never called by our word
>   *Missa,* the Mass. When the Sacrifice was finished, the assembled faithful were dismissed by the Deacon, in the form usual at all public
>   meetings. Later, the word *missa* having been adopted, the confusion
>   of ideas became complete, when by the putting of a capital M to this
>   formula, it ended in *Ite Missa est,* being thus translated amiss: Go,
>   the Mass is said. In Masses at penitential times, in Lent, for
>   example, instead of the *Ite Missa est,* the Deacon says *Benedicamus
>   Domino;* the faithful are not dismissed, because it is supposed that
>   they would like to remain longer in prayer, during these days of
>   expiation. The *Ite Missa est* is consequently a sign of joy, and, as
>   such, it is excluded from Requiem masses: a Song of joy would be out
>   of keeping with a Mass breathing only sadness and supplication.
>
> The *Ite Missa est* having been said, the Priest turns again to the
>   Altar, and bowing somewhat, with his hands joined, he says: *Placeat
>   tibi Sancta Trinitas obsequium servtutis meae, et praesta ut
>   Sacrificium, quod oculis tuae majestatis indignus obtuli, tibi sit
>   acceptabile, mihique et omnibus, pro quibus illud obtuli, sit, te
>   miserante, propitiabile. Per Christum Dominum nostrum. Amen.* This
>   prayer is a kind of epitome made by the Priest, reminding the Holy
>   Trinity of all he has just been doing, begging acceptance of this
>   Sacrifice, and that it may be profitable to all those for whom he has
>   been praying.

Answer (score 0):

We had a very detailed (if somewhat ill-tempered) discussion of this issue in another forum. It is not easy to summarise the line of thought, so it might be better just to have a look at it:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/missa.2529289/

Answer (score -1):

I've read it fittingly and perfectly means "It is accomplished". The same last words of Our Lord on the cross.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you elaborate a little more on how this works? Is *missa* a good translation of "accomplished" or should it be understood less literally? Would "it is accomplished" be used in similar situations as *ite, missa est*? You can edit your answer to add details.

Comment: I think you're thinking of "consummatum est" (Jn 19:30), which were Christ's last words on the cross.